# How to display cards horizontally from database in php

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I need to display cards horizontally from my database using PHP
My code is below

```
function getHighlights($conn){0  
    $q = "SELECT *, MONTHNAME(date) AS themonth, DAYOFMONTH(date) AS theday, YEAR(date) AS theyear FROM highlights ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,3";
    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

    while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){


        echo '
                <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="card-deck mt-5 mb-4">
                        <div class="card col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                            <img src="../thadd/images/'.$page['image'].'" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">'.$page['title'].'</h5>
                            <p class="card-text mb-5">'.$page['message'].'</p>
                            <div class="text-center mb-3">
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Read More &rarr;</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                                    Posted on Tuesday by '.$page['author'].'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>


        ';
```

}

Comment: You need to state what is not working. Are there any error messages? Is the code not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: There are no error messages it just displays vertically instead of horizontally

Comment: `div class="row-fluid"` <- this is why.

Comment: even when i remove it...it still doesn't stack horizontally...please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Generally, move the row out of the loop as shown in the following **pseudo code**.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  -- WHILE LOOP --
    <div class="col">
      -- OUTPUT DATA --
    </div> <!-- col -->
  -- END WHILE --
  </div><!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

Read the bootstrap grid
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/